# Drop-down in kendo-ui not retrieving data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am working on the test project where i fill dropdown list from web api...
Using [ThisDemo](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/editing-custom) as it is....

This all worked fine one time and now it consistently showing console error which i have stated at the end of question...

I am sure there is problem only in targeting template

> {template: "#=Status.StatusName#"}

...i am not sure if this is the right way....but when i remove this code part error disappears but dropdown show undefined instead of StatusName...

The view code (i have used selected script)

```
...
    schema: {
        model: {
            id: "ProjectId",
            fields: {
                ProjectId: { editable: true, nullable: false, type: "number" },
                ClientId: { editable: true, nullable: false, type: "number" },
                Name: { editable: true, nullable: true, type: "string" },
               // Status: { editable: true, nullable: true, type: "string" },
               Status: { defaultValue: { StatusID: 1, StatusName: "Completed" } },
               IsActive: { editable: true, nullable: false, type: "boolean" },
            }
        }
    }
});

$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: dataSource,
    pageable: true,
    toolbar: ["create"],
    scrollable: false,
    sortable: true,
    groupable: true,
    filterable: true,
    columns: [
        { field: "Name", title: "Project Name", width: "170px" },
        //{ field: "Status", title: "Status", width: "110px" },
        { field: "Status", title: "Status", width: "180px", editor: statusDropDownEditor, template: "#=Status.StatusName#" },
        { field: "IsActive", title: "Active", width: "50px" },
        { command: "", template: "<a href='Project/Task'>Manage Task</a>", width: "30px", filterable: false },
        { command: "", template: "<a href='Project/Setting'>Setting</a>", width: "30px", filterable: false },
        { command: ["edit", "delete"], title: "&nbsp;", width: "80px" }
    ],
    editable: "popup"
});

function statusDropDownEditor(container, options) {
    $('<input required data-text-field="StatusName" data-value-field="StatusID" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
        .appendTo(container)
        .kendoDropDownList({
            autoBind: false,
            dataSource: {
                type: "odata",
                transport: {
                    read: "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Categories"
                }
            }
        });
}
```

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'StatusName' of
>   null(anonymous function) @
>   VM1415:1pt.ui.DataBoundWidget.extend._rowsHtml @
>   kendo.all.min.js:31pt.ui.DataBoundWidget.extend._renderContent @
>   kendo.all.min.js:32pt.ui.DataBoundWidget.extend.refresh @
>   kendo.all.min.js:32b.extend.proxy.b.isFunction.i @
>   jquery.min.js:3i.extend.trigger @ kendo.all.min.js:9ht.extend._process
>   @ kendo.all.min.js:11ht.extend.success @
>   kendo.all.min.js:11ht.extend.read.n._queueRequest.n.online.n.transport.read.success
>   @ kendo.all.min.js:11pt.extend.read.n.success @
>   kendo.all.min.js:11b.Callbacks.c @
>   jquery.min.js:3b.Callbacks.p.fireWith @ jquery.min.js:3k @
>   jquery.min.js:5b.ajaxTransport.send.r @ jquery.min.js:5

**If someone have any idea please help, any kind of help will be appreciated thanks for your time**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is linked to the data returned by the odata service.  The data looks like this:

```
ProductID : 1,
ProductName : "Chai",
SupplierID : 1,
CategoryID : 1,
QuantityPerUnit : "10 boxes x 20 bags",
UnitPrice : 18.0000,
UnitsInStock : 39,
UnitsOnOrder : 0,
ReorderLevel : 10,
Discontinued : false,
Category : {
    CategoryID : 1,
    CategoryName : "Beverages",
    Description : "Soft drinks, coffees, teas, beers, and ales"
}
```

As you can see, there's no `Status` in the data returned by the odata service.  A missing field (like `Status`) will be parsed as an `undefined` value.  However, if you try to get a property of that `undefined` object (like your template does), you end up with an error because you can't do `undefined.undefined`.

As a side note; `defaultValue` ain't supported by the [kendo model](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/model).